# Delete from array of object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this. The result is shown by console.log()

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
  name:"SOMEVALUE"
  partyDetails"SOMEVALUE"
  __proto__:Object
1:
  name: "SOMEVALUE"
  partyDetails: "SOMEVALUE"
  __proto__:Object
2:
  name:"SOMEVALUE"
  partyDetails: "SOMEVALUE"
  __proto__: Object
3:
  name:"SOMEVALUE"
  partyDetails:"SOMEVALUE"
  __proto__: Object
4:
  name:"SOMEVALUE"
  partyDetails: "SOMEVALUE"
  __proto__:Object
length:5
__proto__:Array(0)
```

After deleting from the object by this command,

```
delete  $scope.excelInfo.columnDefs[3];
delete  $scope.excelInfo.columnDefs[4];
```

I get this on console.log

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, empty × 2]
 0:
   name:"SOMEVALUE"
   partyDetails:"SOMEVALUE"
   __proto__:Object
 1:
   name:"SOMEVALUE"
   partyDetails:"SOMEVALUE"
   __proto__:Object
 2:
   name:"SOMEVALUE"
   partyDetails:"SOMEVALUE"
   __proto__:Object
 length:5
 __proto__:Array(0)
```

How you see there are *empty × 2* in the last array of objects, after delete.

What should I do to remove this 2 empty rows?

This 2 empty row make my data wrong in the view.

Is there any good solution?

I do not want to check if data equal to null.

Thanks a lot

Comment: just take a look at :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript  
as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
$scope.excelInfo.columnDefs.splice(3,2)
```

e.g.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr.splice(3,2);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank the `splice()` help me. I have voted your answer. And after some minutes I will accept it as you answer the first

Comment: One more time thanks for your answer.
I have found other solution too here is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50702953/4553685

Comment: Welcome. There are many ways of doing the same thing. Choose the one that suits you. That's how I do :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `splice()` to remove last two object without setting `undefined` as it does when you use `delete`

```js
var arr = [
  {
    name:"SOMEVALUE1"
  },
  {
    name:"SOMEVALUE2"
  },  
  {
    name:"SOMEVALUE3"
  },  
  {
    name:"SOMEVALUE4"
  },  
  {
    name:"SOMEVALUE5"
  }
];

arr.splice(3,2)
console.log(arr);
```

Or using `delete` you need to also filter the defined objects only,

```js
var arr = [
  {
    name:"SOMEVALUE1"
  },
  {
    name:"SOMEVALUE2"
  },  
  {
    name:"SOMEVALUE3"
  },  
  {
    name:"SOMEVALUE4"
  },  
  {
    name:"SOMEVALUE5"
  }
];

delete arr[3];
delete arr[4];
var res = arr.filter(item => item);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank the splice help me. I have voted your answer

Comment: One more time thanks for your answer.
I have found other solution too here is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50702953/4553685

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array instead of using `delete`.

```
$scope.excelInfo.columnDefs.splice(3, 2);
//                                 ^  ^
//                                 |  |
//                                 |  Number of elements to remove
//                                 Index at which to start removing
```

`splice()` modifies the array in place, so there is not need to reassign it.

Comment: Thank the `splice()` help me. I have voted your answer

Comment: One more time thanks for your answer.
I have found other solution too here is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50702953/4553685